# Representing boolean values in JSON

Tags: python, json

Say i have a file.json that contains the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Shirt1",
    "product_id": "001234"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shirt2",
    "product_id": "005678"
  }
]
```

Using Python3, i want to add to both dictionaries the following lines:

```
"type": "external"
"reviews_allowed": false
```

This is my code:

```
import json
import os

with open("file.json", "r", encoding="utf8") as in_file:
INP = json.load(in_file)
DATA = []
for item in INP:
    item["type"] = "external"
    item["reviews_allowed"] = "false"
    DATA.append(item)
    with open("file2.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
        out_file.write(json.dumps(DATA, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
os.rename("file2.json", "file.json")
```

However, I get the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Shirt1",
    "product_id": "001234",
    "type": "external",
    "reviews_allowed": "false"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shirt2",
    "product_id": "005678",
    "type": "external",
    "reviews_allowed": "false"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to get rid of the double quotes around *false*?
Thank you very much in advance for your time!

Comment: use `False` instead of `"false"`.

Comment: That was quick enough! Thank you VERY much dear friend!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`false` is [recognised](http://json.org) as its own type in JSON:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or `true` or
>   `false` or `null`, or an object or an array.

In python, the JSON `false` maps directly to the `False` `bool` value:

```
>>> json.dumps({'val' : False})
'{"val": false}'
```

Comment: Wow. Apparently we submitted at precisely the same second. Of course, your answer is more complete... +1

Comment: @Robᵩ We both had the same idea, regardless of presentation, so returned the upvote :-)

Answer (score 7):

The JSON concept `false` maps directly to the Python concept `False`. Use this line:

```
item["reviews_allowed"] = False
```

Comment: I'll accept COLDSPEED's answer, as he commented first in the original question. I hope that this is ok with everybody :-)

Comment: Here's a simple rule: upvote every answer that helped. Accept the answer that solves the problem, or solves it best. Don't worry about who came first. Regardless, thanks for accepting an answer! It really helps the site work better when people do that.